# Create similar decision tree model from R to Python using H2O

Tags: python, r, decision-tree, h2o

I am currently trying to build a decision tree model using H2O.

I saw a few questions, saying that we can use a random forest by twisting the command inside.

How can I change the R code to H2O Python code?

```
tree = rpart(test ~ ., control = rpart.control(minbucket = nrow(data_test)/100, maxdepth = 2))
```

The one I have seems weird and does not work!

```
rf_model = H2ORandomForestEstimator(balance_classes=True, ntrees=1, max_depth=2,
                                 mtries=10, seed=123, score_each_iteration=True)

rf_model.train(x=features, y='test', training_frame=h2o_df)
```

Comment: A single-tree random forest is also known as a single tree.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the following H2O function : **h2o.randomForest()** ([link with an example](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/drf.html))

Regarding your parameters, for min_bucket, I would try **min_rows = 1** even though, min_rows is applied to all leafs and not only the terminal leaf.